# Building a scheduler with sql, php. Most efficient way

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am creating a system that requires a schedular for a particular task. Users may pick from times 24 hours a day, 7 days a week.

I came up with a few options for the database storage, but I don't think either one is the most efficient design, so I'm hoping for some possible alternatives that may be more efficient.

On the user side I created a grid of buttons with 2 loops to create the days, and the times, and I set each a unique value of $timeValue = "d".$j."-t".$i;

So d1-t0  will be Saturday at Midnight   d3-t12= Tuesday at Noon, and so forth.

So, in the database I was first going to simply have a ID, day, time  set up, but that would result in a possible 168 rows per event

Then I tried an ID, day, and time 0-23 (a column for each hour of the day) And I was simply going to have a boolean set up. 0 if not selected, 1 if it is.

This would result in 7 rows per event, but I think querying that data might be a pain.

I need to perform a few functions on this data. On each day, list the number of selected times into an array. But I don't believe having a select statement of SELECT * from schedule where time0, =1 or time1= 1 .... ect will work, nor will it produce the desired array. (times=(0,3,5,6,7...)

So, this isnt going to work well. 
My overall system will need to also know every event that has each time selected for a mass posting.

"Select * from table where time = $time (0-23) and day= $day (1-7)

Do action with data...

So with this requirement, I'm going to assume that storing the times as an array within the database is likely not the most efficient way either.

So am I stuck with needing up to 168 rows of data per event, or is there a better way I am missing? Thanks

Update:

To give a little more clarity on what I need to accomplish:

Users will be creating event campaigns in which other users can bid on various time slots for something to happen. There will likely be 10-100 thousand of these campaigns at any one time and they are ongoing until the creator stops them. The campaign creators can define the time slots available for their campaign.

At the designated time each day the system will find every campaign that has an event scheduled and perform the event.

So the first requirement is to know which time slots are available for the campaign, and then I need the system to quickly identify campaigns that have an event on each hour and day and perform it automatically.

Comment: Are you familiar with other programming languages than php?

Comment: I woulld have an eventId hooked into a group blast or individual person into a junction table or association table. I would not make 168 rows / columns or do that overkill. The table (junc/assoc) would merely have a datetime. And you do date math, say every 5 minutes (whatever) to see if somethings needs to be launched. It is fired off my mysql's built-in Event Scheduler. I have a Junction tables link and 3 Event-related links off my profile page.

Comment: Currently I'm most familiar with PHP/ SQL  but I've been looking at NoSQL database types and other languages, I just don't know much about them yet, but I'm thinking this may be a solution for a column orient database maybe? 

Drew, I don't really understand your solution.